# Understading google geocoding service component filters

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I was testing the components filters when I came across something I was not expecting: **using a filter will improve the results of some queries**. The address I tested was "Avenida de Almirante Reis, 61 C/V.D, Lisboa".

[Without the filter](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061%20C/V.D,%20Lisboa&sensor=false) the result will only point to a Locality, while if I [add a country filter](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061%20C/V.D,%20Lisboa&components=country%3aPT&sensor=false) it will point to an exact address.

Which leads me to doubt my knowledge on filters. The only modification a filter should do is to reduce the set of answers, not *change* it, which is what happens in this case.

I would like to know this because I'm using Google's Geocoding Service and will need to explain (to a certain degree) why I get the results I get, which means understanding this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this possibly hav something to do with Regional Biasing?

Answer (score 1):

No and yes.

Component filters are meant to restrict results, not change them.
Both your examples return just the country now, but these work:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061%20Lisboa
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061%20Lisboa&components=country%3aPT

However, see this Note in the [Component Filtering documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering):

**Note**: Each address component can only be specified either in the address parameter or as a component filter, but not both. Doing so may result in `ZERO_RESULTS`.

It seems to be OK to repeat country, so the 2nd link works, although according to this note it'd be better to use this:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061&components=country%3aPT

But if you do the same with the street name, it does result in `ZERO_RESULTS`:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Avenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis,%2061%20Lisboa&components=country%3aPT%7Aroute%3AAvenida%20de%20Almirante%20Reis